# PyQt: self.setScene(self.scene) AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'setScene'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Aim is to see the scrollbars in the window:
The function of drawing scrollbars has been taken from here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/52415/PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsScene

What does the error mean and what am I supposed to do to solve it?

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QAction,\
        QKeySequence, QLabel, QItemSelectionModel, QMessageBox, QFileDialog, QFrame, \
        QDockWidget, QProgressBar, QProgressDialog

from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL, QSettings, QSize, QPoint, QVariant, QFileInfo, QTimer, pyqtSignal, QObject


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.darkGray, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.viewport().setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self._pan = False
        self._draw = False
        self._moved = False
        self._sel = False
        self.pen = None
        self.penid = None
        self.cmap = None
        self.penwidth = 4
        self._redoStack = []
        self._histStates = []
        self._baseRects = [] 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 42, in <module>
    GUI = Window()
  File "temp.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.setScene(self.scene)
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'setScene'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indicating that `Window` is a `QMainWindow`:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
```

so `Window` is not a QGraphicsView.

so in the example that shows this implicit that Window must be a `QGraphicsView`, the solution is to change `QMainWindow` to `QGraphicsView`.

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.darkGray, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
        self.setScene(self.scene)

        self.setDragMode(QtGui.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtGui.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.viewport().setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self._pan = False
        self._draw = False
        self._moved = False
        self._sel = False
        self.pen = None
        self.penid = None
        self.cmap = None
        self.penwidth = 4
        self._redoStack = []
        self._histStates = []
        self._baseRects = [] 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()
GUI.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```